# Usage of the word Just

Tags: grammar, adverbs

We were talking in a group about two components of my Salary one Offshore and another Onsite.
There I said

> Last year I just got the Offshore Hike and not the onsite hike.

Now I want to know if the sentence

> Last year I just got the Offshore Hike

is equivalent to

> Last year I only got the Offshore Hike

I know the second one sounds better, but I just want to know if the first one (with the word 'just') is also right, as we know the context.

Comment: *Just* can mean *only*, but it can also mean *very recently*. When I read your example sentence, I assumed at first (incorrectly) that you'd been using it to mean "very recently." It wasn't until I finished the question that I realized you'd meant it in the  other sense . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 'Just' can mean 'only' like in your example

> just adverb (ONLY) ​ B1 only; simply:
>
> "Would you like another drink?" "OK, just one more." It was just a
>   joke.

[Just (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just)